# How can i hook a Prestashop module a the mobile template?

Tags: mobile, prestashop

In Prestashop 1.5, I want to hook an existing prestashop module to the default mobile template.
Can it be done using the Administration platform or do I have to tinker the classes/controllers/FrontController.php file?

Cheers

Comment: Hi, what module do you want to use with the mobile template?

Comment: The HomeFeatured module. I managed to include the template I wanted by tinkering with the sitemap.tpl file inside the theme's mobile folder; it that how it's supposed to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, I solved this by overriding the FrontController class and assigning my own hook (in the example the display_left_column hook) in smarty:

```
<?php

class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore {

public function initContent() {
    parent::initContent();

    if ($this->context->getMobileDevice() != false) {
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN' => ($this->display_column_left ? Hook::exec('displayLeftColumn') : ''),
        ));
    }

}
```

Then I echo'd the content of this hook in the mobile index.tpl:

```
<div data-role="content" id="content">
    {$HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN}

    {hook h="DisplayMobileIndex"}
    {include file='./sitemap.tpl'}
</div><!-- /content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up editing the sitemap and the header templates to directly include the ones of the desired modules. It works, although it's not really "pretty", so to speak.